# Journey decision split with contact data not working

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, data-designer

I'm trying to set up a journey where the entry source is Salesforce Data (from the campaign members object).  Contacts enter the journey but my decision split is not working. I'm trying to use contact data to filter members down one path based on the status field on the campaign member object as their status may change during the course of the journey.  when I set up the decision split, it says "At least one attribute in this filter criteria could produce multiple matching values. By default, Journey Builder uses the first matching value. You can use attribute-to-attribute comparison to determine the right match."  I've tried researching attribute to attribute comparison and trying different things but I'm now completely confused.  What exactly is this message saying?  That multiple campaign members could have that status so I need to specify the exact campaign?  campaign member?  I've tried adding to the filter the campaign ID, matching campaign member ID in contact data to same in journey data all to no avail.  What am I missing?